# What is meant by 'bad clustering' in k-means ++ paper?

Tags: clustering, k-means

Arthur and Vassilvitskii, 2006 say that:

"There are many natural examples for which the algorithm generates arbitrarily bad clusterings (i.e., $\frac{\phi}{\phi_{OPT}}$ is
unbounded even when $n$ and $k$ are fixed). Furthermore,
these examples do not rely on an adversarial placement
of the starting centers, and the ratio can be unbounded
with high probability even with the standard randomized seeding technique."

Where $n$ are the number of observations, $k$ the number of clusters. $\phi$ is the minimization objective, the sum of the squared distances
between each point and its closest center. $\phi_{OPT}$ is most likely (although not explicitly defined) the value of the minimization objective under the optimal clustering.

What is the consequence of a ratio being unbounded and how can it be possible with $\frac{\phi}{\phi_{OPT}}$? I don't understand how bad clustering is implied by the above definition.

Reference: Arthur, D., & Vassilvitskii, S. (2006). k-means++: The advantages of careful seeding. Stanford.